# Recent Inbox Messages number wrong

Tags: support, global-inbox

I'm a user of Stack Overflow and trying to help people solve their problems. However what I sometimes see is that the number of messages in 'Recent Inbox Messages' is incorrect.

Just now I had 2 displayed as the number, but when I click on the icon I saw only one `recent` message - i.e. a highlighted one.

What is happening?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One of the following might have happened:

- If you receive multiple comments *on the same post*, this will increase the message counter, but in the dialog only the last comment will be shown. (The API still returns all comments, and therefore the mobile apps will show all of them as well.)
- Somebody deleted their comment or answer to your question, between you clicked the inbox and the dialog opened.